# A word that means "revelling in being dirty"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, that wonderful feeling you get when you have been camping for three nights without a shower. Or when pulling apart and eating a crab with your hands. Or when you stand out in the rain on purpose.

I'm looking for a word that has a similar vibe to "hedonism", "debauchery", but with less sexual connotations and more emphasis on actual dirt. "Carefree" or "primal" would usually fit in this context, but not precisely.

Comment: To [***wallow** in filth*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wallow+in+filth%22) is a particularly common collocation in this general area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to **wallow**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wallow)

> to roll about or lie in water, mud, dust, etc., as for refreshment to
>   indulge oneself; luxuriate; revel

Answer (score 0):

A single word to describe a wide range of activities usually not considered genteel? I would say "**fun**". Doesn't have a specific application to "dirt" but neither does "pulling apart and eating a crab with your hands" or at least I hope dirt isn't involved in this specific activity.

All the examples that you gave are what I consider "fun".

But I think the *phrase* "like a pig in mud" is closer to the true feeling of participating in the example activities you mentioned.